# Receiving and processing emails in application

Tags: ruby, email

I'm currently building an open-source issue management application for my company (will open it up when it's finished) and we got a feature request that I'm not sure how to handle.

They asked if it would be possible to send emails to, say, issue@mydomain.com, which would then parse the body and create the issue within the application.

I'm really not sure where to start.  Is there a way to go about this outside of setting up our own SMTP servers and writing a full-fledged email handling application to run on the mail server?

FYI, we use Google Apps for our email servers now.

Comment: Talk them out of using email, it will save you headaches. You can't trust users to stick to a uniform, delimited format. Especially not coworkers. Go do some jQuery mobile tutorials, get together a scratch demo and show them how much cooler it is to use your phone camera to submit an attachment. They'll forget all about the email...

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle this is to have the emails go into a particular mailbox.  Then, use the Ruby IMAP library:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html

You can read in the messages, get the subject, see if it matches a pattern, or even look for text patterns in the body.  In the old days, we would often write email handlers that would be automatically run when a message came in.  But nowadays, I see a lot more apps just running a cron, looking for new messages, parsing them, and then doing something with them like your app needs to do.  Email is so convenient for users, I definitely understand why your company wants to explore using it.

My suggestion assumes, of course, that you can funnel support@ into an imap compatible account.  Gmail is compatible, you could test with it.